# typescript how do i infer params of constructor to default class type?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I want a function of class can use a type from arguments of constructor
but i don't know how to do that

```js
class Foo<T1, T2=any>{  // if i set T2=any i will lose the type
    a: string = 'a'
    constructor(private readonly config: { params: T2 }) { }

    selectT2(v: keyof T2) { }

    selectT1(t:keyof T1){}
}

type Value1={a1:string,b1:string}

// I only want to input type T1 here, and T2 is dynamically retrieved from params.
const foo = new Foo<Value1>({ params: { a:'1',b:'2',c:'3 '} }) 

// The user inputs this when they create a new class. Foo is a class library,
// Yes you can either use 'typeof' or declare a new type for that. However, it would
// make my library too complex :)

foo.selectT1('a1') // it should suggest a1, b1
foo.selectT2('a') //  it should suggest a b c
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAjAGmigTAXjADsBPAPgG9poB6a6ASwDMHoIBTAF23yOJYHd6IENBDx20DgAs2k4gAc2AWABQVKmABcrDgCd6hAObQ80AORgzq9dGDxCEPQFdgHeLoAU8-QDcwHWV02MAATexA+O0JGekNtSnkwXTAAWwhtXGgAXwBKaEos1Wt1dhA2V1wPH20AazZieGZcPIKitRK2Moq0Dw5NOoamtBzyQpUx1Q4FWQA1MBAnNjQ8cjA0TUd9IwwAI3XNg0MJlVpoAElocL5+Ii43BkJ5Jzvp7DRoGSCsIhDuBhgQsRCKl6MB5hFoEE9PQ2D42L9GLp4CloIlkmkAHSqKKOaCMRAmaCENj8OCIJBzBZLUgeBJJVLpfLQLRmNBmXaaMw4dnATkAZnMWWyeTapxQMmgTnYugeTw4MGk9Bg-BkhEkMkiQX8sjARJJtnAUAxZPg-2ZBsgMBA9B2yV0xAwqlOAE02DAGk5bERoGx6NI2DKpbIzFNFI0zJcZSFyuAgubiaTQ7J8TLpP5jQAJeD8WEBrB+6D8eBOEAhJ10FJgOrQFJ8a22pJ8NymuwpeRlAAe0E0OTa+PgGNK5Q46A8FjZeVOBYgUmLpdYTkMhjdXDWWD2qn7g86w8qFg7ZkndAYXBnc9+EEXy9xup2tjaQA)

Comment: maybe this one helps https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype

Comment: can you fix on playground link @MaksatRahmanov

Comment: TS doesn't support partial type argument inference (see [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)), so there's no way to write  You either specify both manually (as you did with `bar`) or you let the compiler infer both as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WPK3Zm).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thank for your help the problem is i only have T1 type. T2 create dynamic on user input that config.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  How can you not "have" the type?  If someone is calling it with a value `v` in TypeScript code, you can write `typeof v` in TypeScript.  If it is being called at *runtime* then TypeScript doesn't exist anymore and there's no issue with generics.  Could you show via a [mre] exactly what the problem is?

Comment: @jcalz Thank i update the link on playground. the main problem  is i only want input T1 and T2 should get  from constructor. i can't declare a new type or use `typeof` for it.

Comment: As I said at first: there is unfortunately no support for partial type argument inference in TS. It's a missing feature, requested at [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  There are various workarounds like currying or using a dummy parameter, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NaRqPm), but they aren't intuitive.  Does that fully address the question? Or do you think I am misunderstanding or missing something about your question?  If it addresses the question I'll collect it into an answer; if not, what specifically remains to be addressed?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you so much for that. create wrapper function is good too me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to call a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function or construct a generic class, and there are multiple type parameters, you either need to *explicitly specify* all the type arguments (give or take [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults)), or let the compiler *infer* all the type arguments.  TypeScript currently does not support *partial type argument inference* where you specify some and the compiler infers the rest. There is a longstanding feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) to change this, but for now it's not part of the language.

---

The best advice I have is to just specify the type you don't want to specify.  This can be done via [the `typeof` type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html):

```
const params = { a: '1', b: '2', c: '3 ' };
const foo = new Foo<Value1, typeof params>({ params });
// const foo: Foo<Value1, { a: string; b: string; c: string; }>
```

You might not want to do that for some reason, but I don't see this as any worse than the workarounds I can present below.

---

The most common workaround here is to [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the generic function at the type level.  So instead of `<T, U>(u: U) => F<T, U>` you have `<T>() => <U>(u: U) => F<T, U>`.  But that adds an extra function call.  This becomes stranger when you're using a generic *class*, because then you have to build a factory function: instead of `new <T, U>(u: U) => F<T, U>` you have `<T>() => new <U>(u: U) => F<T, U>`.

Here's how I'd do that with your example:

```
class _Foo<T1, T2>{
    a: string = 'a'
    constructor(private readonly config: { params: T2 }) { }
    selectT2(v: keyof T2) { }
    selectT1(t: keyof T1) { }
}
function Foo<T1>() {
    const Foo: new <T2>(config: { params: T2 }) => Foo<T1, T2> = _Foo;
    return Foo;
}
type Foo<T1, T2> = _Foo<T1, T2>;
```

I've renamed your class out of the way so that the factory function can have the name.  And to use it you use you have to calling `Foo<Value1>` as a function and construct the class returned by that, which requires multiple parentheses in interesting places:

```
const foo = new (Foo<Value1>())({ params: { a: '1', b: '2', c: '3 ' } })
// const foo: Foo<Value1, { a: string; b: string; c: string; }>
```

---

Another workaround is to add a dummy parameter corresponding to the type you want to specify manually, and then you supply a dummy argument from which the compiler can infer the type parameter.  Like this:

```
class Foo<T1, T2>{ 
    a: string = 'a'
    constructor(dummyT1: T1, private readonly config: { params: T2 }) { }
    selectT2(v: keyof T2) { }
    selectT1(t: keyof T1) { }
}

const foo = new Foo(
    null! as Value1,
    { params: { a: '1', b: '2', c: '3 ' } }
);
// const foo: Foo<Value1, { a: string; b: string; c: string; }>
```

Since it's just a dummy parameter of type `T1`, we don't really need to supply a real `T1` value.  So I use `null!` (which is `null` at runtime and [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) at compile time so it can be passed to anything) and just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that it's of type `Value1`.

---

Those are the possibilities as I see them.  It's up to you which, if any, you want to use; I don't think any of them are obviously better or worse than any others. I suppose it depends on the use case.  Maybe one day microsoft/TypeScript#26242 will be addressed and then something more straightforward will be available.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-WcfdTIhWygkajyJUSYsBm4rJkomealrKapmxvaJOp6iA+mGkwv3yQD5kqpZ1lCUAA)

Comment: thank for your answer I end to do this `this.create<Foo>().with(params)`.